# jtable to image conversion not happening properly

Tags: java, image, swing, jtable

I am trying to create a buffered image from a table, when i add the table to a application frame and set the size I am able to view it properly but when I convert it into an image I can only see the first row with the table and the rest outside the table and without the header.

The code generate the table is

```
  table = new JTable();

    String[] table_header = null;

    TextAreaRenderer textAreaRenderer = new TextAreaRenderer();
    table_model = new DefaultTableModel() {

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    table.setModel(table_model);
    table.setSize(300, 700);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
    createTableDataSet(input1, input2, varient, headertype);
    TableColumnModel cmodel = table.getColumnModel();
    table_header = obtainTableHeader(headertype);
    for (int i = 0; i < table_header.length; i++) {
        cmodel.getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(textAreaRenderer);
    }


    return table;
```

The code to generate the image is :

```
 JTableHeader header =table.getTableHeader();
    int w = Math.max(table.getWidth(), header.getWidth());
    int h = table.getHeight() + header.getHeight();
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
    header.paint(g2);
    g2.translate(0, header.getHeight());
    table.paint(g2);
    g2.dispose();
    try {
        ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File("year.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The image of the table is [image: here]

update 1 :I may have found the cause of the problem . I am using the following code snippet in order to increase the size of the cell so that the text gets wrapped into the cell. Including the code which is causing the problem 
       private final DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();

```
// Column heights are placed in this Map 
private final Map<JTable, Map<Object, Map<Object, Integer>>> tablecellSizes = new HashMap<JTable, Map<Object, Map<Object, Integer>>>(); 

/** 
 * Creates a text area renderer. 
 */ 
public TextAreaRenderer() { 
    setLineWrap(true); 
    setWrapStyleWord(true); 
} 

/** 
 * Returns the component used for drawing the cell.  This method is 
 * used to configure the renderer appropriately before drawing. 
 * 
 * @param table      - JTable object 
 * @param value      - the value of the cell to be rendered. 
 * @param isSelected - isSelected   true if the cell is to be rendered with the selection highlighted; 
 *                   otherwise false. 
 * @param hasFocus   - if true, render cell appropriately. 
 * @param row        - The row index of the cell being drawn. 
 * @param column     - The column index of the cell being drawn. 
 * @return - Returns the component used for drawing the cell. 
 */ 
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, 
                                               boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) { 
    // set the Font, Color, etc. 
    renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, 
            isSelected, hasFocus, row, column); 
    setForeground(renderer.getForeground()); 
    setBackground(renderer.getBackground()); 
    setBorder(renderer.getBorder()); 
    setFont(renderer.getFont()); 
    setText(renderer.getText()); 

    TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel(); 
    setSize(columnModel.getColumn(column).getWidth(), 0); 
    int height_wanted = (int) getPreferredSize().getHeight(); 
    addSize(table, row, column, height_wanted); 
    height_wanted = findTotalMaximumRowSize(table, row); 
    if (height_wanted != table.getRowHeight(row)) { 
        table.setRowHeight(row, height_wanted); 
    } 
    return this; 
} 

/** 
 * @param table  - JTable object 
 * @param row    - The row index of the cell being drawn. 
 * @param column - The column index of the cell being drawn. 
 * @param height - Row cell height as int value 
 *               This method will add size to cell based on row and column number 
 */ 
private void addSize(JTable table, int row, int column, int height) { 
    Map<Object, Map<Object, Integer>> rowsMap = tablecellSizes.get(table); 
    if (rowsMap == null) { 
        tablecellSizes.put(table, rowsMap = new HashMap<Object, Map<Object, Integer>>()); 
    } 
    Map<Object, Integer> rowheightsMap = rowsMap.get(row); 
    if (rowheightsMap == null) { 
        rowsMap.put(row, rowheightsMap = new HashMap<Object, Integer>()); 
    } 
    rowheightsMap.put(column, height); 
} 

/** 
 * Look through all columns and get the renderer.  If it is 
 * also a TextAreaRenderer, we look at the maximum height in 
 * its hash table for this row. 
 * 
 * @param table -JTable object 
 * @param row   - The row index of the cell being drawn. 
 * @return row maximum height as integer value 
 */ 
private int findTotalMaximumRowSize(JTable table, int row) { 
    int maximum_height = 0; 
    Enumeration<TableColumn> columns = table.getColumnModel().getColumns(); 
    while (columns.hasMoreElements()) { 
        TableColumn tc = columns.nextElement(); 
        TableCellRenderer cellRenderer = tc.getCellRenderer(); 
        if (cellRenderer instanceof TextAreaRenderer) { 
            TextAreaRenderer tar = (TextAreaRenderer) cellRenderer; 
            maximum_height = Math.max(maximum_height, 
                    tar.findMaximumRowSize(table, row)); 
        } 
    } 
    return maximum_height; 
} 

/** 
 * This will find the maximum row size 
 * 
 * @param table - JTable object 
 * @param row   - The row index of the cell being drawn. 
 * @return row maximum height as integer value 
 */ 
private int findMaximumRowSize(JTable table, int row) { 
    Map<Object, Map<Object, Integer>> rows = tablecellSizes.get(table); 
    if (rows == null) return 0; 
    Map<Object, Integer> rowheights = rows.get(row); 
    if (rowheights == null) return 0; 
    int maximum_height = 0; 
    for (Map.Entry<Object, Integer> entry : rowheights.entrySet()) { 
        int cellHeight = entry.getValue(); 
        maximum_height = Math.max(maximum_height, cellHeight); 
    } 
    return maximum_height; 
}
```

This is causing the cell not to be displayed properly. Once I remove this code the table is beig generated properly by including kleopatra's code. But I am stuck with the problem of word wrap in the cell.

Thanks,
Bhavya

P.S. I have used the same code above to generate an image when the table object is created using new JTable(row,fields) in my code the serialized hashmap is  read and inserted into the table_model

Comment: What about table.getPreferredSize().height ? What does it return?

Comment: @Oltarus sorry I realised that it was because i was adding the table to the application frame, if i try to create an image directly I am getting a value for the height of the table but the header and the data is not properly visible in tha table

Comment: I see that the header.getHeight returns 0, I am adding the header to the table_model and adding the table_model to the tabel. Is there a work around for this ?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you have to do the layout work for *all* components you want to paint to the image, that is in this case both the table and the tableHeader, by setting their sizes (below the pref is used).

BTW, adding to a JScrollPane is not helpful (as you have seen), except when the pane is realized - adding the header is done by the table in addNotify.

```
    JTable table = new JTable(new AncientSwingTeam());
    JTableHeader header =table.getTableHeader();
    table.setSize(table.getPreferredSize());
    header.setSize(header.getPreferredSize());
    int w = Math.max(table.getWidth(), header.getWidth());
    int h = table.getHeight() + header.getHeight();
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
    header.paint(g2);
    g2.translate(0, header.getHeight());
    table.paint(g2);
    g2.dispose();
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi));
    showInFrame(label, "image of table");
```

Edit: comment on TextAreaRenderer

The general rule is to never-ever-ever change the calling table in the renderer's getXXRendererComponent, the table given as parameter is to be regarded read-only, strictly. Breaking the rule can lead to ugly loops (setting a new rowHeight while painting triggers a new painting request) or artefacts (there is no guarantee when the renderer is called, so the correct rowheight might or not have been set) as you see here.

Instead do the measuring somewhere outside. On detecting a change (f.i. in the model) which might lead to updating the sizes, walk the rows, measure all its cells and update to the largest. Simply extract all your sizing code from the renderer.

Comment: as easy that could be, my bad I again complicated simple things  +1

Comment: @kleopatra thank you for this code snippet but has only solved my problem partly, the table header is now visible.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues I can see here.

- You should use printAll rather than paint when drawing to the image.
- <strike>The height of the table is set when the pack method is called, but this is before the table is populated. If you are creating the image immediately after generating the table then the size may not be set. You should populate the table before you pack the frame - that should ensure the size is available when you need it.</strike>

EDIT: Following your code change I would suggest removing the scroll pane (as kleopatra suggested) and then using printAll. paint should not be used for images as it can use double buffering. To see the header you will need to set its size using the code provided by kleopatra. The header's size is independent of the table so calling setSize on the table does not alter the header.

Comment: i just replaced paint with printAll and checked, I am still facing this issue. yes I am creating an image immediately after creating the table, I just tried it with the application frame even then I am getting the same image as above. Also I dont want to use JFrame or ApplicationFrame as I will pass the table object to be displayed by a servlet.

Comment: @Russ Hayward `JTable` should by added to the `JScrollPane`, then maybe suggestion about `ViewPort` ..., but nobody know by order OP's descriptions

Comment: @mKorbel random guesses again ;-)

Comment: @mKorbel The table is added to the JScrollPane here: new JScrollPane(table). I agree that the scroll pane is definitely not a good idea.

Comment: curious: what's wrong with double-buffering? As long as the image comes out correct I tend to not care ...

Comment: @kleopatra here is an old tutorial that explains the problem: http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-Printing.html

Comment: Hmm ... still don't see the relation: it talks about printing (to a graphics provided by the printer system), here the graphics comes from the BufferedImage. Wouldn't expect much of a problem in that case. Thanks for the pointer, will keep my eyes open for code which prints into a bufferedImage :-)

Answer (score 0):

I went through the post at this location [Truncated JTable print output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894129/truncated-jtable-print-output) and included the answer at that location it seems to be working fine now.

Thank you for your help

Comment: that answer is wrong, even though it might work in your particular case. Do. Not. Change. Caller's.State.In.Renderer. See my answer here and my comment there