# width of the JTable is constant and so cannot view the graph properly

Tags: java, swing, jtable

This is a continuation of the problem here [jtable to image conversion not happening properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593499/jtable-to-image-conversion-not-happening-properly), I have implemented the answers mentioned in the previous link.

I now see that the width of the table is always constant at 300, this is okay when the table height is small, for tables which are very long the tables become really thin and the image of this cannot be used for rendering at all.

The number of columns in most tables are constant to 4.

Please do let me know if there is anything that I can try here.

Comment: *"Please do let me know if there is anything that I can try here."*  You can try asking a question..

Answer (score 0):

Set the size of the scroll pane instead.

```
pane.getViewport().setViewSize(300, 700)
```